# Не работает Alt + insert в Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, intellij-idea

Для генерации метода в студии нажимаю Alt + insert, на что студия вообще не реагирует. Хоткей использую между методами в MainActivity. Что делать ?

Comment: какая операционка ?

Comment: операционка - винда

Answer (score 4):

Идите в

> File > Settings > Keymap > Main menu > Code > Generate...

и посмотрите, что у вас там установлено, если ничего, то назначьте - ПКМ > Add Keyboard ShortCut

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А если там Alt+Insert и установлен, но все равно ни чего не происходит? Под Linux, 2.3.3

Answer (score 0):

Идите в File > Settings > Keymap > Main menu > Code > Generate...
 и посмотрите, что у вас там установлено, если ничего, то назначьте - ПКМ > Add Keyboard ShortCut. Если там все назначено, то скоррее всего что вы используете ноутбук и у Вас включен функционал клавиши Fn попробуйте Fn+Alt+Insert или отключите Fn